# Compute $E\left[ \|U\|^2 \mid U+V \in S , V\in S \right]$ is $U,V$ are standard normal, $S=\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^k: x_1 \le x_2 \le ... \le x_k \}$

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Let $U \in \mathbb{R}^k$ and $V\in \mathbb{R}^k$ be two independent standard normal vectors (i.e., $U \sim \mathcal{N}(0,I)$ and  $U \sim \mathcal{N}(0,I)$ ).   Define a set $S$ as
\begin{align} 
S=\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^k: x_1 \le x_2 \le x_3 \le ... \le x_k  \}
\end{align}

We are interested in computing the following conditional expectation
\begin{align}
E\left[ \|U\|^2 \mid   U+V \in  S , V\in S \right].
\end{align}

My guess is that, most likely, there is no closed-form expression, so an upper bound would be also fine.

One upper bound I that I tried is via Cauchy-Schwarz:
\begin{align}
E\left[ \|U\|^2 \mid   U+V \in  S , V\in S \right]&= \frac{E\left[ \|U\|^2 1_{ \{  U+V \in  S , V\in S \}} \right] }{P [  U+V \in  S , V\in S ]}\\
&\le \frac{ \sqrt{E\left[ \|U\|^4 \right]} \sqrt{ P [  U+V \in  S , V\in S ]} }{P [  U+V \in  S , V\in S ]}\\
&= \frac{ \sqrt{E\left[ \|U\|^4 \right]}  }{\sqrt{ P [  U+V \in  S , V\in S ]}}.
\end{align}

Now computing $E\left[ \|U\|^4 \right]$ is simple.  However, $P [  U+V \in  S , V\in S ]$ is not so much.   I tried using inclusion-exclusion principle
\begin{align}
 P [  U+V \in  S , V\in S ]&=   P [  U+V \in  S  ]+  P [   V\in S ]- P [  U+V \in  S \text{ or } V\in S ]\\
&= \frac{2}{k!}-P [  U+V \in  S \text{ or } V\in S ]
\end{align} 
where we used that  $P [  U+V \in  S  ]=  P [   V\in S ]=\frac{1}{k!}$

Comment: Well, you can obtain a bound via $(U\in S, V\in S) \implies (U+V \in S, V\in S)$, s.t. $P(U+V\in S , V\in S) \ge P(U\in S, V\in S) = 1/k!^2$.  But I would imagine the resulting bound can be pretty loose.

Comment: BTW when you said $U,V$ are standard normal vectors I assume this includes covariance matrix $\Sigma = I$, i.e. the components are independent, right?  (You must have, or else you cannot really conclude $P(V\in S) = 1/k!$)

Comment: Thank you for the bound. Even though it might be loose. This is already an approach and we had zero before.   I updated my answer.

Comment: For $k=2$ (BTW you still had the dimension as $n$ in the def of $S$ in the title and body text), this can be solved exactly, at least in non-closed form, because $V \in S$ is equiv. to the dot product $V \cdot (1,-1) \le 0$ and we can condition on $V \cdot (1,-1) = v \le 0$ to then find out the exact region of allowed $U$, namely $U \cdot (1,-1) \le -v$.  However, this approach does not generalize to $k > 2$.

Comment: For another (loose? trivial?) upperbound, I think $E[||U||^2 \mid U+V \in S, V \in S] \le E[||U||^2]$, the unconditioned value.  Would that be interesting to you?

Comment: @antkam  I don't think so.  Conditioning might increase the expectation.

Comment: oh!  then you _would_ find the bound interesting. I don't have a formal proof, but here's my gut feel: Obviously any $U\in S$ is always "allowed", regardless of choice of $V\in S$. For other $U \notin S$ though, smaller magnitude $U$ will be "allowed" by more choices of $V\in S$, while larger magnitude $U$ will be "allowed" by fewer choices of $V\in S$. This creates a bias on the conditional distribution of $U$ toward those of smaller magnitude. If $E[||U||^2] = k$ is a good enough bound for your "ulterior motive" (i.e. reason why you asked this question), then this may be a viable approach.

Comment: @antkam  Sorry, I didn't mean to say I am not interested. I mean to say I'd don't think it holds.

Comment: My gut tells me it holds, so the question becomes: would an upperbound of $E[||U||^2] = k$ (if proven) be good enough for whatever underlying reason which made you ask this question in the first place?  If it is, I will try to find some time to justify / prove my gut feel.  I'm not sure I can do it, and even if I can it's sure to be tedious, so I'd rather not spend the time unless you tell me a bound of $k$ is interesting to you.

Comment: Dear @antkam, yes the bound $k$ would be very interesting to me. Not that this would greatly improve a previous bound which is of the order $\sqrt{k!  E[\|U\|^4]}$.

Comment: You mean "**Note** that it would greatly improve..." right? :)

Comment: @antkam Yes, note. I am making a lot of typos today :)

Comment: @antkam   I have uploaded a new question that is related to this one. You can find here.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3495059/find-mathbbp-uv-in-s-v-in-s-where-u-v-are-standard-normal-vectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is just writing up the idea in @antkam's comment - I hope that's ok. I'll show:

> $$\mathbb E\left[ \|U\|^2 \mid   U+V \in  S, V\in S\right]\leq k$$

The crucial point is that if we fix $V\in S$ and the direction $\widehat U:=U/\|U\|,$ then $\|U\|^2$ is increasing in $\|U\|,$ but the characteristic function $1_{U+V\in S}$ is decreasing in $\|U\|,$ because $S$ is convex:

$$U+V,V\in S \implies \lambda U + V = \lambda(U+V)+(1-\lambda)V\in S\text{ for $0\leq \lambda\leq 1$}$$

So we can use the result that the covariance between a decreasing function and an increasing function is non-positive. You can find proofs on this site for example at [Covariance of increasing functions of random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2423658/covariance-of-increasing-functions-of-random-variables).
It is important that the direction $\widehat{U}$ and magnitude $\|U\|$ are independent - the pdf of $U$ factorizes as a (constant) function of direction multiplied by a function of magnitude. We get

$$V\in S\implies\operatorname{Cov}(\|U\|^2,1_{U+V\in S}\mid \widehat U, V)\leq 0\text{ a.e.}$$

More explicitly, $$V\in S\implies\mathbb E[\|U\|^21_{U+V\in S}\mid \widehat U, V)\leq k\mathbb P[U+V\in S\mid \widehat U, V]\text{ a.e.}$$
Both sides can then be integrated over the event $V\in S$ and divided by $\mathbb P[V\in S]$ to give
$$\mathbb E[\|U\|^21_{U+V\in S}\mid V\in S)\leq k\mathbb P[U+V\in S\mid V\in S].$$

(Alternatively, use the [law of total covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_covariance) conditioned on $V\in S,$ which happens to reduce here to the law of total expectation because $\|U\|^2,\widehat U,V$ are independent. This gives $\operatorname{Cov}(\|U\|^2,1_{U+V\in S}\mid V\in S)\leq 0,$ which is the same thing.)

This means
$$\mathbb E[\|U\|^2 \mid U+V\in S, V\in S]=\frac{\mathbb E[\|U\|^21_{U+V\in S}\mid V\in S]}{\mathbb P[U+V\in S\mid V\in S]}\leq k.$$

Comment: +1 Not only is it OK, I really appreciate the answer!!  I've been struggling to prove this on and off for a few days, and always got stuck with some messy Jacobian (which I'm not even sure I should be using).  I'm beginning to suspect I'm missing some powerful theorem(s), and your provided them.  THANKS A TON!!  :)  Separate question: this bound $k$, while proven, is sort of "ignorant".  I have a vague geometric intuition (esp. based on $k=1,2$ cases) that the bound has to be quite a bit tighter (see my orig comments on "big $U$ being disallowed more often").  What's your gut feel on this?

Comment: Quick question. Can you explain a bit more why indicator function is a decreasing function of $\|U\|?

Comment: @Boby - Because $U + V \in S \implies \lambda U + V \in S$ for any $\lambda \in (0,1)$.  So the indicator starts at $1$ (when $U=0$, and conditioned on $V \in S$) and at some point might (or might not) drop to $0$ and then must stay there.  As to why $\lambda U + V \in S$, that can be proved easily if you consider each $x_j \le x_{j+1}$ requirement separately.

Comment: Hmm...  Actually Boby has a point: the proof as written seems to say $1_{U+V\in S}$ is decreasing for any $V$, but I _think_ that's false.  I.e. I _think_ it is only decreasing for any $V \in S$...?

Comment: @antkam: I've edited to add the important condition $V\in S$ - indeed $1_{U+V\in S}=0$ at $\|U\|=0$ if $V\not\in S.$ I don't have much intuition for how tight this bound is - the conditioning biases towards smaller values, but a very severe constraint could force behavior similar to $U\in S$ so that $U$ and $V$ are sort of independent - consider how $\mathbb E[\|X\|^2 \mid X<t]\approx \mathbb E[\|X\|^2]$ if $X\sim N(0,1)$ and $\epsilon\approx 0.$ Based on some dodgy simulations I wouldn't rule out $\mathbb E\left[ \|U\|^2 \mid   U+V \in  S, V\in S\right]\sim k.$

Comment: Yeah, it would be great to also have a lower bound on this.  However, I suspect it is a difficult one to find.

Comment: Can you also expand on the step with the law of total covariance?  I tried to replicate, it but get lost with conditionings.

Comment: @Boby: I've expanded a bit - hopefully it's easier to see what's going on

Comment: Dear Dap, can you take a look the following question that I recently asked: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/418204/show-that-mathbbp-a-v-le-z-vz-mathbbpav-ge-z-vz-text-a-s-i