# Find $\mathbb{P}[ U+V \in S, V \in S], $ where $U,V$ are standard normal vectors, $S=\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^k: x_1 \le x_2 \le ... \le x_k \}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution

Let $U \in \mathbb{R}^k$ and $V\in \mathbb{R}^k$ be two independent standard normal vectors (i.e., $U \sim \mathcal{N}(0,I)$ and  $U \sim \mathcal{N}(0,I)$ ).   Define a set $S$ as
\begin{align} 
S=\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^k: x_1 \le x_2 \le x_3 \le ... \le x_k  \}
\end{align}

Our goal is to find an order tight bound on $\mathbb{P}[ U+V \in S, V \in S]$.

Here are some preliminary bounds.

**Upper Bound:** Using monotonicty of probability measure
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}[ U+V \in S, V \in S] \le \min (\mathbb{P}[ U+V \in S],\mathbb{P}[ V \in S])=\min \left(\frac{1}{k!} ,\frac{1}{k!} \right)=\frac{1}{k!} .
\end{align}

**Lower Bound:**
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}[ U+V \in S, V \in S] \ge \mathbb{P}[ U \in S, V \in S]= \left( \frac{1}{k!} \right)^2
\end{align} 
where we have used that $ U \in S, V \in S \Rightarrow  U+V \in S, V \in S$.

Note that the orders are very different here.  This question is inspired by something that I asked earlier [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3488273/compute-e-left-u-2-mid-uv-in-s-v-in-s-right-is-u-v-are-standard).

Comment: It is certainly $(\frac 1{k!})^2$ up to an exponential in $k$ factor but finding the exact exponent may be difficult. How much do you care about the size of the exponential correction?

Comment: @fedja  at this point, I don't care much about the size of the exponential correction.  So any bound that improves this would be useful.

Comment: @fedja Sorry to bother you. But can you at least share an idea of how to improve the upper bound?  Maybe I can take over from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the delay.

We have to figure out when $(U,U+V)$ lies in the cone $C=S\times S\subset \mathbb R^{2k}$ of angular measure $\frac 1{(k!)^2}$. Note that then $(U,V)$ lies in the cone $TC$ where $T$ is the linear transformation given by $(x,y)\mapsto (x,y-x)$. So we need to find or estimate the angular measure of $TC$ in $\mathbb R^{2k}$. The determinant of $T$ is $1$, so it preserves volumes. The norm of $T^{-1}$, however, is $\alpha=\sqrt{\frac{3+\sqrt 5}2}$, so if $TC$ intersects the unit ball by volume $V$, then $C$ intersects the ball of radius $\alpha$ by volume at least $V$. Passing to the angular measures, we see that the angular measure of $TC$ is at most the angular measure of $C$ times $\alpha^{2k}$, so we get an upper bound $\frac{1}{(k!)^2}(\frac{3+\sqrt 5}{2})^k$. That is not sharp, of course, but it gives you a general idea of what to expect.

Comment: Ok. Can we put this into some formulas?    I think what you are saying is that $(U,U+V)=A( U,V)$ for some matrix $A$.   So,   $ \mathbb{P}[ (U,V+U) \in C] = P[ (U,V) \in A^{-1} C ]$, correct?  Now, I couldn't really fall of the other steps.  Specifically, I think you get to the upper bound  $P[ (U,V) \in A^{-1} C ] \le  \| A^{-1} \|^k P[ (U,V) \in  C ]$. However, I cannot follows this part. Sorry, for being slow. Maybe you can give a bit more explanation for me here.

Comment: @Boby Let's try to figure out where you are getting lost. The main thing I use is that if the angular measure of the cone  $C\subset \mathbb R^n$ is $a$, then, on the one hand, the probability that the standard Gaussian vector belongs to $C$ is also $a$ and, on the other hand, the volume of $C$ intersected with $B(0,r)$ is $r^n a{\rm vol}(B(0,1))$. Is that much clear?

Comment: Thanks. It would be nice to do it slowly.   Yes, this part is clear.

Comment: @Boby Now let's look at the angular measure of $TC$ (in my notation). Assume it is $a$. then $a{\rm vol}(B(0,1))={\rm vol}(TC\cap B(0,1))={\rm vol}(T^{-1}[TC\cap B(0,1)])$. Is this clear?

Comment: The first equality is clear.   Why does it hold that ${\rm vol }(TC \cup B(0,1))={\rm vol}(T^{-1}[TC \cup B(0,1))$?  Is it because  ${\rm vol}(T^{-1}[TC \cup B(0,1))= det(T^{-1})  {\rm vol}(TC \cup B(0,1)) $ and  $det(T^{-1}) =1$.

Comment: @Bovy Yes, this is because the determinant is $1$, so $T^{-1}$ is volume-preserving. Should we continue?

Comment: Yeah. Let's continue... So $a=\frac{{\rm vol}(T^{-1}[TC \cup B(0,1)]}{{\rm vol}( B(0,1))}$, right?

Comment: The last step is that $T^{-1}[TC\cap B(0,1)]=T^{-1}[TC]\cap T^{-1}[B(0,1)]\subset C\cap B(0,\|T^{-1}\}$, so the last volume is at most the angular measure of $C$ times $\|T^{-1}\|^{2k}{\rm vol}(B(0,1))$. Now just cancel ${\rm vol}(B(0,1))$ and interpret the angular measure as probability. Any problems in this part?

Comment: @Boby By the way, I wrote $\cap$ (intersection) where you are writing $\cup$ (union). I presume it is just a typo on your part :-)

Comment: Yes, it's a typo. Sorry :).   I think I follow this now.  Thank you for your patience.

Comment: @Boby You are welcome :-)

Comment: Sorry, one more question. How did you compute the norm of the operate $T^{-1}$?

Comment: @Boby The usual thing: what is the best $a>0$ such that $(x+y)^2+x^2\le a^2(x^2+y^2)$? (or, alternatively, you can find the eigenvalues of a $2\times 2$ matrix). Anyway, the exponential factor is not sharp, so it doesn't matter too much what exactly it is.

Comment: Hi fedja, I was wondering if you can take a look at the following question of mine: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4405600/how-to-simplify-mathbbp-axz-ge-0-xz