# How to simplify $\mathbb{P}[ aX-Z \ge 0| X+Z]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution, conditional-probability

Consider two independent random variables $(X,Z)$ where $Z$ is standard normal  and $X$ has a pdf $f_X$. I want to see if we can somehow 'simplify' the following probability
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}[ aX-Z \ge 0| X+Z]
\end{align}
for a given $a>0$.

For example, can this be written as an integral that only involves the joint of $f_{X,Z}$? Basically, how far can we simplify this expression or re-write it in a nice way.

I was thinking of writing this probability as follows
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P} \left[ \left[ \begin{array}{c}  a \\ -1 \end{array} \right ] [X,Z] \ge 0 \mid \left[ \begin{array}{c}  1 \\ 1 \end{array} \right ] [X,Z]\right]
\end{align}
and then using some kind of mapping theorem, but I couldn't really do it.

Comment: Recall that conditioning relative to a random variable really means conditioning to the sigma-field it engenders. So, rewritting the conditioning is of little help. Besides calculating the distribution of $(aX - Z, X + Y)$ and the using the usual way to find conditional distributions for absolutely continuous random variables (i.e. something like $f(a,b)/f(a)$), I don't know any other way.

Comment: @WilliamM.  Thanks. This is what I thought too.   This question is related to something that I asked here. Maybe you will be intersted: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/418204/show-that-mathbbp-a-v-le-z-vz-mathbbpav-ge-z-vz-text-a-s-i